# How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

If I wanted to programatically assign a property to an object in Javascript, I would do it like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop = "value";
```

But in TypeScript, this generates an error:

> The property 'prop' does not exist on value of type '{}'

How am I supposed to assign any new property to an object in TypeScript?

Comment: `interface DynamicObject {
    [key: string]: any
}


const object:DynamicObject;

object['key']='Test value'
`

Comment: You should use what they call declaration merging. Read about it. An example is in passport.js' index.d.ts

Answer (score 1126, accepted):

### Index signatures

It is possible to denote `obj` as `any`, but that defeats the whole purpose of using typescript. `obj = {}` implies `obj` is an `Object`. Marking it as `any` makes no sense. To accomplish the desired consistency an interface could be defined as follows, using an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

```
interface LooseObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

var obj: LooseObject = {};
```

OR to make it compact:

```
var obj: {[k: string]: any} = {};
```

`LooseObject` can accept fields with any string as key and `any` type as value.

```
obj.prop = "value";
obj.prop2 = 88;
```

The real elegance of this solution is that you can include typesafe fields in the interface.

```
interface MyType {
    typesafeProp1?: number,
    requiredProp1: string,
    [key: string]: any
}

var obj: MyType ;
obj = { requiredProp1: "foo"}; // valid
obj = {} // error. 'requiredProp1' is missing
obj.typesafeProp1 = "bar" // error. typesafeProp1 should be a number

obj.prop = "value";
obj.prop2 = 88;
```

### `Record<Keys,Type>`  utility type

*Update (August 2020): @transang brought up the [`Record<Keys,Type>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) in comments*

> `Record<Keys,Type>` is a Utility type in typescript. It is a much cleaner  alternative for key-value pairs where property-names are not known.
> It's worth noting that `Record<Keys,Type>` is a named alias to `{[k: Keys]: Type}` where `Keys` and `Type` are generics.
> IMO, this makes it worth mentioning here

For comparison,

```
var obj: {[k: string]: any} = {};
```

becomes

```
var obj: Record<string,any> = {}
```

`MyType` can now be defined by extending Record type

```
interface MyType extends Record<string,any> {
    typesafeProp1?: number,
    requiredProp1: string,
}
```

While this answers the Original question, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54445030/2605574) by @GreeneCreations might give another perspective on how to approach the problem.

Comment: I think this is the best solution now. I think at the time the question was asked index properties like this were not yet implemented in TypeScript.

Comment: It does make sense when you have dynamic data. If you are receiving dynamic data from API, to build form, and then sending back dynamic values to api, it does make sense. Any is there for a reason, obviously you should strongly type most of stuff which is not dynamic, but in dynamic cases you can't strongly type.

Comment: now, you can write `Record<string, any>`, instead of `{[key: string]: any}`

Comment: It is now recommended to use `Record<string, unknown>` to avoid using the `any` type

Comment: why 'interface' instead of 'type' ?

Comment: I am using a props object for the JSX h function using Typescript.  If I use this answer, then the added property is always string and can only be accessed using props["name"] and not props.name.  However, the underlying code in JSX assumes a props.name syntax.  Hence the only solution that seems to work for me is the one defined by @Crwth.

Answer (score 108):

Or all in one go:

```
  var obj:any = {}
  obj.prop = 5;
```

Comment: What's the point of TypeScript if I have to cast so many things to `any` in order to use it? Just becomes extra noise in my code.. :/

Comment: @AjaxLeung You should very rarely cast to `any`. TypeScript is used to catch (potential) errors at compile time. If you cast to `any` to mute errors then you lose the power of typing and may as well go back to pure JS. `any` should ideally only be used if you're importing code for which you cannot write TS definitions or whilst migrating your code from JS to TS

Comment: No matter what  the best practice or purpose of typescript is, this is the right answer to the question.

Comment: @M.Arjmandi - it's really not. The question is asking how you should approach this in terms of typescript. The whole point of typescript is to avoid the annoying side of javascript being dynamic - everything in javascript is effectively cast to any be default. It's objectively not a good answer.

Answer (score 107):

This solution is useful when your object has Specific Type. Like when obtaining the object to other source.

```
let user: User = new User();
(user as any).otherProperty = 'hello';
//user did not lose its type here.
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for one-off assignments.

Comment: This answer worked for me because for facebook login I had to add properties to the **window** object.  My first use of the **as** keyword in TypeScript.

Answer (score 88):

I tend to put `any` on the other side i.e. `var foo:IFoo = <any>{};` So something like this is still typesafe:

```
interface IFoo{
    bar:string;
    baz:string;
    boo:string;     
}

// How I tend to intialize 
var foo:IFoo = <any>{};

foo.bar = "asdf";
foo.baz = "boo";
foo.boo = "boo";

// the following is an error, 
// so you haven't lost type safety
foo.bar = 123;
```

Alternatively you can mark these properties as optional:

```
interface IFoo{
    bar?:string;
    baz?:string;
    boo?:string;    
}

// Now your simple initialization works
var foo:IFoo = {};
```

[Try it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20IFoo%7B%0A%09bar?:string;%0A%09baz?:string;%0A%09boo?:string;%20%09%0A%7D%0A%0A//%20How%20I%20tend%20to%20intialize%20%0Avar%20foo:IFoo%20=%20%7B%7D;%0A)

Comment: +1 for being the only solution that keeps type safety. Just make sure you instanciate all non-optional properties directly after it, to avoid bugs biting you later on.

Comment: Does this actually work?  After compiling I still have <any>{} in my javascript.

Comment: `I still have <any>{` then you haven't compiled. TypeScript would remove that in its emit

Comment: These days, `var foo: IFoo = {} as any` is preferred. The old syntax for typecasting was colliding with TSX (Typescript-ified JSX).

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me, how does`<any>{}` respect the type of `IFoo`?

Comment: You can also simplify it down to `var foo = {} as IFoo`

Answer (score 51):

Although the compiler complains it should still output it as you require. However, this will work.

```js
const s = {};
s['prop'] = true;
```

Comment: yes well, this is not really type script way, you loose intellisense.

Comment: Works nice for object with dynamic structure (cannot be defined in an interface)

Comment: do not use var.. instead use let or const

Comment: "dynamically"....

Answer (score 48):

I'm surprised that none of the answers reference Object.assign since that's the technique I use whenever I think about "composition" in JavaScript.

And it works as expected in TypeScript:

```
interface IExisting {
    userName: string
}

interface INewStuff {
    email: string
}

const existingObject: IExisting = {
    userName: "jsmith"
}

const objectWithAllProps: IExisting & INewStuff = Object.assign({}, existingObject, {
    email: "jsmith@someplace.com"
})

console.log(objectWithAllProps.email); // jsmith@someplace.com
```

**Advantages**

- type safety throughout because you don't need to use the `any` type at all
- uses TypeScript's aggregate type (as denoted by the `&` when declaring the type of `objectWithAllProps`), which clearly communicates that we're composing a new type on-the-fly (i.e. dynamically)

**Things to be aware of**

1. Object.assign has it's own unique aspects (that are well known to most experienced JS devs) that should be considered when writing TypeScript.

   - It can be used in a mutable fashion, or an immutable manner (I demonstrate the immutable way above, which means that `existingObject` stays untouched and therefore doesn't have an `email` property. For most functional-style programmers, that's a good thing since the result is the only new change).
   - Object.assign works the best when you have flatter objects. If you are combining two nested objects that contain nullable properties, you can end up overwriting truthy values with undefined. If you watch out for the order of the Object.assign arguments, you should be fine.

Comment: For me, in instances where you need to use this to display data it seems to work fine, but when you need to add entries of modified types to an array, this doesn't seem to work too well. I resorted to dynamically composing the object and assigning it in one line, then assigning the dynamic properties in successive lines. This got me most of the way there, so thank you.

Comment: I tried this with an Express Request object and discovered that the "immutable" method `Object.assign( {}, req, myObj )` will break the Request object in unexpected ways, such as causing headers to become undefined.

However, as suggested above the "mutation" method worked great: `Object.assign( req, myObj )`.

Answer (score 27):

One more option do to that is to access the property as a collection:

```js
var obj = {};
obj['prop'] = "value";
```

Comment: This is the most concise way. `Object.assign(obj, {prop: "value"})` from ES6/ES2015 works, too.

Answer (score 23):

You can create new object based on the old object using the spread operator

```
interface MyObject {
    prop1: string;
}

const myObj: MyObject = {
    prop1: 'foo',
}

const newObj = {
    ...myObj,
    prop2: 'bar',
}

console.log(newObj.prop2); // 'bar'
```

TypeScript will infer all the fields of the original object and VSCode will do autocompletion, etc.

Comment: nice, but in case you need to use prop2 in e.g. prop3, will be hard to implement

Comment: Not sure if I follow the statement - there is no `prop3` in this example.

Answer (score 23):

Late but, simple answer

```
let prop = 'name';
let value = 'sampath';
this.obj = {
   ...this.obj,
   [prop]: value
};
```

Answer (score 13):

you can use this :

```
this.model = Object.assign(this.model, { newProp: 0 });
```

Comment: You don't need `this.model = `.

Comment: `this.model = { ...this.model, { newProp: 0 }};`

Answer (score 12):

Case 1:

```
var car = {type: "BMW", model: "i8", color: "white"};
car['owner'] = "ibrahim"; // You can add a property:
```

Case 2:

```
var car:any = {type: "BMW", model: "i8", color: "white"};
car.owner = "ibrahim"; // You can set a property: use any type
```

Comment: If you use `any` this way, you might as well not use TypeScript. Don’t use `any` if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a special version of `Object.assign`, that automatically adjusts the variable type with every property change. No need for additional variables, type assertions, explicit types or object copies:

```
function assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): asserts target is T & U {
    Object.assign(target, source)
}

const obj = {};
assign(obj, { prop1: "foo" })
//  const obj now has type { prop1: string; }
obj.prop1 // string
assign(obj, { prop2: 42 })
//  const obj now has type { prop1: string; prop2: number; }
obj.prop2 // number

//  const obj: { prop1: "foo", prop2: 42 }
```

Note: The [sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6pgczAHgCoA0iAqgHwAUUyATpgKZQBcihiqcI1EdzxAlMzSo61KKkRVaDRDHF5EAMhKIA3gFgAUIm2IA8gCMAVnWgA6IVjCUa9KEXadufTQF9NmiAlRREcI4gBeVRcAbk0LbHI-QyIVRAAHajh4gEZmACJgODh0xBdnDQB6Qu1PMG9ffzA4AHdEAAs0CQBPeLpVBKTU5m9qGDBMELzNaNNE5JTEYrYoPoHw9Esoo1jO5IAmZgAWdbyC6cQyiujEarrG8ShW9rjx7pm5wbzFDrvN05AAW30RIbcNUZvKYlMBfH7UdwaI5wAA2dFMMLgmGWhgKkKAA) makes use of TS 3.7 [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). The return type of `assign` is `void`, unlike `Object.assign`.

Comment: This `assert` way also works to mix-in any arbitrary property into an existing object/class.  eg. `function addProperty<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends string>(toObj: T, key: K, value: any): assert T is T & { [K]: any } { toObj[key] = value; }`.  I had it returning a new object with the property mixed-in, but that didn't tell TS that the original input object actually got mutated (I had to declare a new `interface` with the mixed-in property(ies) before TS would recognize them). `assert` as the return type takes care of that, with no extra interface defs required.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Simplest will be following

```
const obj = <any>{};
obj.prop1 = "value";
obj.prop2 = "another value"
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you cannot do this:

```
obj.prop = 'value';
```

If your TS compiler and your linter does not strict you, you can write this:

```
obj['prop'] = 'value';
```

If your TS compiler or linter is strict, another answer would be to typecast:

```
var obj = {};
obj = obj as unknown as { prop: string };
obj.prop = "value";
```

Comment: This is if 'noImplicitAny: false' on the tsconfig.json

Comment: Else you can do GreeneCreations answer.

Answer (score 7):

To guarantee that the type is an `Object` (i.e. **key-value pairs**), use:

```
const obj: {[x: string]: any} = {}
obj.prop = 'cool beans'
```

Comment: This solution worked for me because without the additional type information I was still getting this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to add a member to an existing object by

1. widening the type (read: extend/specialize the interface)
2. cast the original object to the extended type
3. add the member to the object

```js
interface IEnhancedPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    sayHello(): void;
}

const p = Promise.resolve("Peter");

const enhancedPromise = p as IEnhancedPromise<string>;

enhancedPromise.sayHello = () => enhancedPromise.then(value => console.info("Hello " + value));

// eventually prints "Hello Peter"
enhancedPromise.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is use safe typing, I recommend you:

```
interface customObject extends MyObject {
   newProp: string;
   newProp2: number;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that is fully type-safe is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518971/288906), but is a little wordy and forces you to create multiple objects.

If you ***must*** create an empty object first, then pick one of these two solutions. Keep in mind that every time you use `as`, you're losing safety.

## Safer solution

The type of `object` is **safe** inside `getObject`, which means `object.a` will be of type `string | undefined`

```
interface Example {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

function getObject() {
  const object: Partial<Example> = {};
  object.a = 'one';
  object.b = 1;
  return object as Example;
}
```

## Short solution

The type of `object` is **not safe** inside `getObject`, which means `object.a` will be of type `string` even before its assignment.

```
interface Example {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

function getObject() {
  const object = {} as Example;
  object.a = 'one';
  object.b = 1;
  return object;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending @jmvtrinidad solution for Angular,

When working with a already existing typed object, this is how to add new property.

```js
let user: User = new User();
(user as any).otherProperty = 'hello';
//user did not lose its type here.
```

Now if you want to use `otherProperty` in html side, this is what you'd need:

```
<div *ngIf="$any(user).otherProperty">
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

Angular compiler treats `$any()` as a cast to the `any` type just like in TypeScript when a `<any>` or `as any` cast is used.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this, and you can add or use any property. (I am using typescript version as  `"typescript": "~4.5.5"`)

```js
let contextItem = {} as any;
```

Now, you can add any property and use it any where. like

```js
contextItem.studentName = "kushal";
```

later you can use it as:

```js
console.log(contextItem.studentName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Store any new property on any kind of object by typecasting it to 'any':

```
var extend = <any>myObject;
extend.NewProperty = anotherObject;
```

Later on you can retrieve it by casting your extended object back to 'any':

```
var extendedObject = <any>myObject;
var anotherObject = <AnotherObjectType>extendedObject.NewProperty;
```

Comment: This is totally the correct solution. Lets say you have an object let o : ObjectType; .... later on you can cast o to any (<any>o).newProperty = 'foo'; and it can be retrieve like (<any>o).newProperty. No compiler errors and works like a charm.

Comment: this brakes intellisense ... is there any way to this this but to keep intellisense?

Answer (score 3):

To preserve your previous type, temporary cast your object to any

```
  var obj = {}
  (<any>obj).prop = 5;
```

The new dynamic property will only be available when you use the cast:

```
  var a = obj.prop; ==> Will generate a compiler error
  var b = (<any>obj).prop; ==> Will assign 5 to b with no error;
```

Answer (score 3):

**dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript.**

to do that You just need to use typescript interfaces like so:

```
interface IValue {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

interface IType {
    [code: string]: IValue;
}
```

you can use it like that

```
var obj: IType = {};
obj['code1'] = { 
    prop1: 'prop 1 value', 
    prop2: 'prop 2 value' 
};
```

Comment: I try with your code, but I don't receive any error: https://pastebin.com/NBvJifzN

Comment: try to initialise the `attributes` field inside `SomeClass ` and that should fix it `public attributes: IType = {};` https://pastebin.com/3xnu0TnN

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Typescript, presumably you want to use the type safety; in which case naked Object and 'any' are counterindicated.

Better to not use Object or {}, but some named type; or you might be using an API with specific types, which you need extend with your own fields. I've found this to work:

```
class Given { ... }  // API specified fields; or maybe it's just Object {}

interface PropAble extends Given {
    props?: string;  // you can cast any Given to this and set .props
    // '?' indicates that the field is optional
}
let g:Given = getTheGivenObject();
(g as PropAble).props = "value for my new field";

// to avoid constantly casting: 
let k = getTheGivenObject() as PropAble;
k.props = "value for props";
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article tackling this very topic:

*Typescript – Enhance an object and its type at runtime*

https://tech.xriba.io/2022/03/24/typescript-enhance-an-object-and-its-type-at-runtime/

Maybe you could take inspiration from Typescript concepts such:

- [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)
- [Key Remapping via as](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)
- [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `any`, you can use do this:

```
type Obj = Record<string, unknown>

var obj: Obj = {};
obj.prop = "value";
obj.prop2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when trying to do a partial update of an object that was acting as a storage for state.

```js
type State = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
};

const newState = { foo: 'abc' };

if (someCondition) {
  newState.bar = 'xyz'
}

setState(newState);
```

In this scenario, the best solution would be to use `Partial<T>`. It makes all properties on the provided type optional using the `?` token. Read more about it in [a more specific SO topic about making all properties on a type optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40076355/742872).

Here's how I solved it with `Partial<T>`:

```js
type State = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
};

const newState: Partial<State> = { foo: 'abc' };

if (someCondition) {
  newState.bar = 'xyz';
}

setState(newState);
```

This is similar to what fregante described in their answer, but I wanted to paint a clearer picture for this specific use case (which is common in frontend applications).

Answer (score 0):

**Use ES6 `Map` whenever a map can take truly arbitrary values of fixed type, and optional properties otherwise**

I think this is the guideline I'll go for. ES6 map can be done in typescript as mentioned at: [ES6 Map in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019542/es6-map-in-typescript)

The main use case for optional properties are "options" parameters of functions: [Using named parameters JavaScript (based on typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108807/using-named-parameters-javascript-based-on-typescript/71679344#71679344) In that case, we do know in advance the exact list of allowed properties, so the sanest thing to do is to just define an explicit interface, and just make anything that is optional optional with `?` as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444150/895245 to get as much type checking as possible:

```
const assert = require('assert')

interface myfuncOpts {
  myInt: number,
  myString?: string,
}

function myfunc({
  myInt,
  myString,
}: myfuncOpts) {
  return `${myInt} ${myString}`
}

const opts: myfuncOpts = { myInt: 1 }
if (process.argv.length > 2) {
  opts.myString = 'abc'
}

assert.strictEqual(
  myfunc(opts),
  '1 abc'
)
```

And then I'll use Map when it is something that is truly arbitrary (infinitely many possible keys) and of fixed type, e.g.:

```
const assert = require('assert')
const integerNames = new Map<number, string>([[1, 'one']])
integerNames.set(2, 'two')
assert.strictEqual(integerNames.get(1), 'one')
assert.strictEqual(integerNames.get(2), 'two')
```

Tested on:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.13",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
export interface QueryParams {
    page?: number,
    limit?: number,
    name?: string,
    sort?: string,
    direction?: string
}
```

Then use it

```
const query = {
    name: 'abc'
}
query.page = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add this declaration to silence the warnings.

```js
declare var obj: any;
```