# Use jquery.handsontable in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, handsontable

I want to use handsontable in typescript

```
$("#dataTable").handsontable({
    data: data,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    contextMenu: true,
    onSelection: function (row, col, row2, col2) {
        var meta = container.handsontable('getCellMeta', row2, col2);
        if (meta.isWritable == false) {
            container.handsontable('updateSettings', { fillHandle: false });
        }
        else {
            container.handsontable('updateSettings', { fillHandle: true });
        }
    },
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        if (row === 0 || container.handsontable('getData')[row][col] === 'readOnly') {
            cellProperties.readOnly = true; //make cell read-only if it is first row or the text reads 'readOnly'
        }
        cellProperties.type = {
            renderer: negativeValueRenderer
        }
        return cellProperties;
    }
});
```

But I get the errors:

```
Error   1   The property 'readOnly' does not exist on value of type ''. 
Error   3   The property 'type' does not exist on value of type ''.
```

how can i fix?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler doesn't like your empty object. It has no information about its type or the properties that may exist on it.

The easiest would be per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript):

```
var cellProperties:any = {}
```