# Why Typescript throws error on legal js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.4

Typescript claims full compatibility with JavaScript, but yet when I write:

```
var obj = {};
obj.x = 1;
```

TypeScript throws an error saying that `obj` doesn't have definition of `x`. Why?

I am using VS2013 along with TypeScript 1.4

Comment: Related: [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)

Comment: To answer to "why": this is because of the [TS inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#type-inference). The type of the variable `obj` is implicitly inferred from the empty object.

Comment: To address your first sentence: valid JavaScript *is* valid TypeScript, but TypeScript is more strict with what it considers valid. For example, `var a = 1; a = "name";` is also valid JavaScript, but TypeScript will throw an error, also because of type inference. Same thing with trying to get or set a property that doesn't exist, like your example. To make your intentions explicit to the compiler, either declare it as of type `any`, or use `obj["x"] = 1;` instead.

Comment: @Tarth, I now understand! After playing with TypeScript a bit more and with your explanations, now I fully understand this issue