# Unable to add property to an existing object in Javascript with Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, javascript-intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm trying some simple Javascript in the new Visual Studio Code. With the following js code:

```
var obj = { abc: "test" };
obj.foo = "bar";
```

I get this error:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ abc: string; }'.
```

However it's a js file rather than ts. Isn't the code valid in Javascript?

Comment: interesting, it works fine for me in a js file

Comment: This issue appears on my friend's vscode too.

Comment: @utility simple javascript file.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually by design.  It may be considered valid JavaScript, but it is not valid TypeScript Syntax.

See [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript), http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1657, and http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397908.

The good news is, JavaScript isn't compiled, so the file will still work correctly on your client, as tsc.exe will never really be run against the .js file.

Comment: Correct, from the video on https://code.visualstudio.com/, Code uses TypeScript under the hood to *verify* all Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule to configure how these situation are handled. The default should be `ignore` in JavaScript but you can configure it to be a warning or an error with this:

```
{
    "javascript.validate.lint.unknownProperty": "ignore"
}
```