# adding property to javascript object in typescript without errors

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript#_=_) article  its quite interesting, but it does not help me when I try to extend a global variable like `window`.

**Test.ts**

```
window.test = {}; //ERROR: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Window'.

(function (test)
{
//do stuff
} (window.test)); //Build: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Window'
```

**Error message:**

> ERROR: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Window'.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Declaration Merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```
interface Window {
    test(): void;
}

window.test = function() {
    // do what ever
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Window%20%7B%0D%0A%09test()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Awindow.test%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20do%20what%20ever%0D%0A%7D))

As you can see you need to declare your new method in the `Window` interface and then the compiler won't complain when you add the actual implementation.

Comment: does it there's something like `interface` in JS or it's just in typescript ?

Comment: @MahmoudZakal `interface` is a typescript thing: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html, as there's no need to such a thing in javascript

Comment: As of today there's a kinda-sorta need to do this in JS, if you're using the TS compiler to do type checking using the `checkJs` option.  In that case, the compiler will complain about `window.test = ...` but is fine with `window["test"] = ...`.

Comment: @Coderer Even if you add `test` to the window interface?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but in *vanilla Javascript* there's no such thing as an interface.  Mahmoud's question was how to tell the compiler that there should be a `.test` property on `window` *in Javascript*; that's what my comment is about.

Comment: @Coderer But, if I understand you correctly, you are using the ts compiler, you just want it to also check regular js files.  If you add `test` to the window interface, won't that also affect how the compiler checks the js?

Comment: When you say "add `test` to the window interface", I think you might mean to create a `.d.ts` file and do the interface definition there (in Typescript, obviously).  That's how I'm being told to accomplish more or less the same thing [in my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372322/26286) and it seems like a pretty poor substitute for allowing me to do it in JSDoc or with a similar (comment) annotation.  I'm increasingly worried that `checkJs` is not ready for prime time.

Comment: @Coderer No, that's not what I mean. It can be added in a `.ts` file, which is the usual use case. In your case you only have `.js` files so you'll need to create a `.d.ts`, but that's a specific case. It sounds to me like your not using typescript right. If you only want static analysis of your js code why not [flow](https://flow.org/)? Also, you know that you can have typescript files (`.ts`) with only js in them? You can keep your entire code, but just change the extension to `.ts` and it will just work.

Comment: OK, I caved and made a `globals.d.ts` and it does get rid of the warnings.  I'm trying to avoid changing extensions so I don't have to re-do my Webpack config, at least in the short term -- this is kind of an experiment, and I might commit to full-on TS eventually :D

Comment: Spoke too soon.  I put `declare var viewer: MyLib.Viewer;` in `globals.d.ts`, and my red squigglies went away -- but VS thinks `viewer` is of type `any`.  I added `import MyLib from "mylib";` to the top of `globals.d.ts` and now the red squiggly came back, as though `globals.d.ts` is no longer being included by the checker.  I'd ask a new question about this but I don't think I have the TS vocabulary to word it intelligently.  Is it to do with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4166)?

Comment: @Coderer If you're using modules (export/import) then you'll need to [augment the global module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was missing.