# How should I tell the Typescript compiler about a global variable defined elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing **vanilla Javascript** and trying to use TS type checking in VSCode by specifying the `checkJs` flag.  (This has been something of an adventure over the past week!)

My project uses ES6 modules bundled by Webpack / Babel; the entry point (`app.js`) exports a global variable:

```
var viewer;
viewer = ...
window.viewer = viewer;
```

I tell other modules about this variable so `eslint` won't bother me:

```
/* global viewer */
var val = viewer.val;
```

This works fine, but now the TS checker is complaining

```
[js] Cannot find name 'viewer'.
```

How can I tell the TS compiler that I've defined this outside of the current file?  Does TS need to be updated to respect the eslint `global` comment, or maybe it has its own comment directive syntax?

Comment: Does this have an answer??

Comment: The closest we've gotten to an answer is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15626) linked in the comments below.  Basically, you have to make a `.d.ts` ("typings") file that "augments" the global namespace. TS (arguably) *should* allow you to use some kind of inline comments to do this but currently does not.

Comment: I wouldn't mind a `index.d.ts` if vscode could load it without a `jsconfig.json`. This should be easier (jsdoc anyone?)

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript definitely does not respect the eslint note, since it is a comment. For telling TS that an external variable is available, you could simply write `declare let viewer: any;` (or with `const` instead of `let`).

Comment: Again, I am not *writing* TS, this is a `.js` file not a `.ts` file; I am using the VSCode `checkJs` option to tell it to do type checking on my (vanilla, Javascript) code.  I kind of feel like I'm the first person on the Internet to use this feature!

Comment: Sorry, the part which I forgot to write was to write that into an external TS file. For your information at [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15626) there is an ongoing discussion about your problem, as weswigham pointed out, it should be possible to just type annotate a simple `var viewer;` in your file, which uses that variable.

Comment: I would strongly prefer not to add a `.d.ts` file to my build just to make the checker happy, but if I have to I guess I'll figure it out.  I saw in the GH discussion that you can just add a `var viewer` but I thought that would shadow (?) the `window.viewer` attached in the other module? I will follow that GH issue because I'd like to see a better resolution for monkey-patching the `window` object in vanilla JS.