# How can I make a generic TypeScript interface extend from another generic interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface, with several elements:

```
export interface Item {
  id: string;
  code: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  level: number;
  seq: number;
  hasChildren: boolean;

  parentObject?: Item;
  children?: Item[];
}
```

I wanted something like the `Partial<T>` which I helpfully discovered here:
[Make all properties within a Typescript interface optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713349/make-all-properties-within-a-typescript-interface-optional#40076355)

However, I would like to make **one** of the fields mandatory. I implemented this:

```
export interface ItemUpdate extends Partial<Item> {
  id: string;
}
```

and that compiled well. However, I would like to avoid declaring it for each interface. For that, I made it more generic:

```
export interface UpdateOf<T> extends Partial<T> {
  id: string; // the ID is the only mandatory value for an update
}
```

However, that is no longer compiling, returning the following error:

```
error TS2312: An interface may only extend a class or another interface.
```

I am running Angular 6.1.5, which comes with Typescript 2.9 (as far as I know).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error message is out of date; there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27890) to update it.  The current rule is that a class or interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types *with statically known members*, since the compiler needs to check whether the types of properties declared in the class or interface are compatible with the types of the corresponding properties (if any) of the base type.  The members of `Partial<Item>` are statically known, while the members of `Partial<T>` are not.  A workaround is to use an intersection type instead of a sub-interface:

```
export type UpdateOf<T> = Partial<T> & {id: string};
```