# How to make optional properties to required based on a condition?

Tags: typescript

Here is my code:

```
interface IOptions {
  clientId: string;
  token: string;
}

interface IComponent {
  name: string;

  parent?: { name: string };
}

async function createComponent(opts?: IOptions): Promise<IComponent> {
  const component: IComponent = { name: '' };

  if (opts) {
    component.parent = { name: `${opts.clientId}-${opts.token}` };
  }

  return component;
}

async function main() {
  const { name, parent } = await createComponent();

  console.log(parent.name);
}
```

I want to make `parent` optional property of `IComponent` interface to required property if the `opts` is existed in `createComponent` function.

For now, I got an error when I use `parent.name` in `main` function.

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

I want the return value's interface of `createComponent` function to be like: `Promise<IComponentRequired>` if `opts` is existed and return `Promise<IComponent>` if `opts` is not existed.  which like this:

```
interface IComponentRequired {
  name: string;

  parent: { name: string };
}
```

My thinking is `IComponent` => `Required<T>` => `IComponentRequired`.

**update**

Here is my try, but didn't work.

```
async function otherMain() {
  const opts: IOptions = { clientId: '123', token: '321' };
  const component: Required<IComponent> = await createComponent(opts);

  console.log(component.parent.name);
}
```

Got error:

> Type 'IComponent' is not assignable to type 'Required'.
>     Types of property 'parent' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ name: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }'.ts(2322)

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713349/make-all-properties-within-a-typescript-interface-optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use overloads to either return the required version or the one where the property is optional:

```
interface IOptions {
    clientId: string;
    token: string;
}

interface IComponent {
    name: string;

    parent?: { name: string };
}

async function createComponent(): Promise<IComponent>
async function createComponent(opts: IOptions): Promise<Required<IComponent>>
async function createComponent(opts?: IOptions): Promise<IComponent> {
    const component: IComponent = { name: '' };

    if (opts) {
        component.parent = { name: `${opts.clientId}-${opts.token}` };
    }

    return component;
}

async function main() {
    const opts: IOptions = { clientId: '123', token: '321' };
    const component: Required<IComponent> = await createComponent(opts);

    console.log(component.parent.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Second error gone. But the first error still there. It seems make sense.