# Typescript access dynamic property with [' '] syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export class Foo{
 someproperty: string;
}
```

I am trying to understand why, when trying to access dynamic object property I can do the following as I saw on one of the answers here:

```
let fooObj: foo = someObj['someproperty'];
```

but by doing this, I get an error.

```
let fooObj: foo = someObj.someproperty;
```

I am trying to understand, why the first method works for accessing/assigning to dynamic objects.

Error:

`"someproperty does not exist on type"`

Question asked before here, answer by Angelo R is the one I am interested in.

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what exactly does it say?

Comment: "someproperty does not exist on type", but on the type it does exist

Comment: it depends on the foo type definition.

Comment: should work, check your spelling

Comment: Guys, in foo definition this property exists.

Comment: Add to your question  the code which defines the type of `someObj` and how you assign a value to it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is just a convention in TypeScript, available for convenience. If you want to access some arbitrary property that is not defined in the type signature of the object, you can use the `["foo"]` notation, and the type checker will not try to enforce that the instance you're accessing has such a property in its type signature.

Comment: More about this in the TypeScript specification: [4.13 Property Access](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1db4f96fd14fc3de5ae3704e925afd6474cfb8f5/doc/spec.md#4.13)

Answer (score 1):

The way I foud to pass propery of object is using `const myproperty = 'name' as const;`

```
type MyObject = {
        name: string,
        age: number;
    }

    let obj:MyObject = {name: 'Ryu', age:30};
    const myproperty = 'name' as const;
    
    console.log(obj[myproperty])
```

For example, if you want to pass parameters on the function called **sum()** to sum all property '**visited**', another time you want to sum all deals in this same function, using property '**deals**', you can put all properties on an **array** and passing a index of this array, **sum(0) or sum(1)**.

```
type Sale = {
    id: number;
    visited: number;
    deals: number;
    amount: number;
 }

let data:Array<Sale> =[{id: 1, visited: 83, deals: 66, amount: 5501},
{id: 2, visited: 113, deals: 78, amount: 8290},
{id: 3, visited: 36, deals: 12, amount: 6096}]

const args = ['visited',  'deals', 'amount'] as const;

 const sum = (property:number) => {

        let total:number = 0;
        data.forEach((element) => {
            
            total += element[args[property]];
        });
        
        return total;
    }
    
console.log(sum(0))  //Visited  
console.log(sum(1))  //deals
console.log(sum(2))  //amount
```

Or you can use `enum` for more general use.

```
 enum CategoryOfSum{
        VISITED = 'visited',
        DEDALS = 'deals',
        AMOUNT = 'amount'
    }
    
    const sum = (type:CategoryOfSum) => {

        let total:number = 0;
        data.forEach((element) => {
            
            total += element[type];
        });
        
        return total;
    }

sum(CategoryOfSum.VISITED)
sum(CategoryOfSum.DEDALS)
sum(CategoryOfSum.AMOUNT)
```