# Set property of a class using a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, ecmascript-6

Is something like this possible?

```
const propName = "x";

class A {
    static propName = 1
    // equivalent to static x = 1
}

A[propName] // evaluates to 1
```

or would it be `(typeof A)[propName]`?

---

For obvious reasons, this is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Did you read this question? It's completely different to what you marked as a duplicate...

Comment: I read the question. There is no property named `x`, just a property named `propName`. So either `A.propName` or `const propName = "propName";`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You should re-open this question. I have no idea why you think that other question is even related - it's not even TypeScript

Comment: That is not equivalent to `static x = 1`, FYI. The meaning of `static propName = 1` does not change just because a string variable `propName` exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, simply as:

```
const propName = "x";

class A {
    static [propName] = 1
    // equivalent to static x = 1
}

A[propName]
```

Comment: 1) Don't assume it's me downvoting. 2) `A[propName]` will compile regardless of whether `x` exists on `A` or not. Try it yourself. This is not type-safe, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43740513/1541563).

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1541563+%5Btypescript%5D)

Comment: This answer is correct; it is using [computed properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#computed-properties), which TypeScript understands as long as the value of the property is statically known as a literal type (so `let propName = "x";` would fail because `propName` would be `string`).

Comment: And as for `A[propName]` compiling whether or not `x` exists on `A`: you would get a warning with `--strict` or `--noImplicitAny` modes.