# How can I add a property to a class dynamically in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How can I add a property to a class in typescript?

```
export class UserInfo {
  public name:string;
  public age:number;
}

let u:UserInfo = new UserInfo();
u.name = 'Jim';
u.age = 10;
u.address = 'London'; // Failed to compile. Property 'address' does not exist on type 'UserInfo'.
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What  are you trying to achieve? The whole purpose of typescript is to have well-defined interfaces and classes so that you don't have surprises. Why can't UserInfo contain an (optional) `address` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)

Comment: @k0pernikus At running, I'd like to add other properties for it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use index signature:

```
export class UserInfo {
    [index: string]: any;
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
}

const u: UserInfo = new UserInfo();
u.name = "Jim";
u.age = 10;
u.address = "London";

console.log(u);
```

Will output:

```
$ node src/test.js
UserInfo { name: 'Jim', age: 10, address: 'London' }
```

Yet note that thereby you are loosing the strict typechecks and introduce potential bugs that a prone to happen in weakly typed languages.

Comment: I have  a generic  type Facade<T extends Record<string, AbstractClass>> and want to access the members like in simple  record: Facade.Member.method() - is it possible in typescript?