# Dynamic object key with Typescript in React event handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Similar but distinct from [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript/39140719)

I have a component with the state type:

```
{
  low: string
  high: string
}
```

And as is a common pattern in React, my event handler is:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  let { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```

With `high` and `low` as `name` attributes on my inputs. Typescript is erroring with:

`Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<State, "low" | "high">'`

Is there a way for me to tell Typescript that I only expect those 2 values? I'd like to avoid explicitly passing the key into the handler but don't want to change the state to something like:

```
{
  low: string
  high: string
  [key: string]: string
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the perfect world we should be able to write something like this:

```
private handleChange = (e: {target: {name: "low" | "high", value: string}}) =>
{
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({[name]: value});
}
```

But unfortunately a reported bug (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) or [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15534)) force us to use some temp workaround like casting to any or such:

```
this.setState({[name]: value} as any);
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the issue links and workaround. `as any` should work fine here.