# Dynamic key access in object literal results in widened typescript signature

Tags: typescript

For the following code:

```
const x = {
    a: 'c',
    b: 'd'
};

const y = {
    [x.a]: 'e',
}
```

the generated types are:

```
typeof x -> {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

typeof y -> {
  [x: string]: string
}
```

Expected type:

```
typeof y -> {
  c: string
}
```

Similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305939/dynamic-object-key-with-typescript-in-react-event-handler?noredirect=1&lq=1) on SO has a solution which is not relevant here

Found the reported [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5579) on Github which says this was fixed but is somehow not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `typeof x.a` is actually a string. Here, x is constant but the value of `x.a` can be changed to any string value.

If the value of `x.a` is not going to change then a possible solution(using [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) added in typescript version 3.4):

```
const x = {
    a: 'c',
    b: 'd'
} as const;

const y = {
    [x.a]: 'e',
}

typeof y -> {
    c: string
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
But to note, this will work with version 3.4 and above. For older ones, we will have to do something like: 
const x = {
    a: 'c' as 'c',
    b: 'd' as 'd'
}.
Could you please update the answer to reflect the version information?

Comment: Thanks, I will do it.

Comment: @HarshVyas Your edit introduced a typo: you mean v 3.4 not 4.3!