# typescript anonymous object with variable based label value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I followed this link:
[How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)

but it shows only how to handle object props names and values with long separate definition of an object.
I wish to know how to do it with an "on the fly" anonymous built object of any type with no previous definition. 
I will show it in the following example.

can't make it to work. unfortunately it takes the variable name as the lable and not the variables value as I wish.

here is the code:

```
var srchTxtlabel: string = '';
if (this.labelType == '1')
    srchTxtlabel = 'srchtxt';
else if (this.labelType == '2')
    srchTxtlabel = 'subject';

this.myService.emit({
    srchTxtlabel : this.val1,
    'va2Label' : this.val2
})
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let emitObj = {};
emitObj[srchTxtlabel] = this.val1;

this.AdvancedSrchEvent.emit(emitObj)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and fast answer. Though I prefer this solution in my case: [srchTxtlabel] : this.val1 . but your of course works great also

Comment: @I.DiZahav glad I was able to help you, pleae accept the answer if you like it