# Dynamically assigning properties to an array of typed objects while mapping in Typescript

Tags: typescript

this has an error:

```
interface TypeA {
  prop1: string
}
interface TypeB extends TypeA {
  prop2: string
}
const ArrA: TypeA[] = [{ prop1: "foo" }]
const ArrB: TypeB[] = ArrA.map(a => {
  a.prop2 = "bar"
  return a
})
```

this gets an error: `[ts] Property 'prop2' does not exist on type 'TypeA'.`

and i want to do this without using `any` in my interface definitions ([like in this Stackoverflow question from 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)). I can't find any other solution on Stackoverflow so I am posing this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
const ArrB: TypeB[] = ArrA.map(a => {
  return {
    ...a,
    prop2: "bar"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to use the `as` keyword for casting and also add `prop2` as an optional param on `TypeA`:

```
interface TypeA {
  prop1: string;
  prop2?: string;
}
interface TypeB extends TypeA {
  prop2: string;
}
const ArrA: TypeA[] = [{ prop1: "foo" }];
const ArrB: TypeB[] = ArrA.map(a => {
  a.prop2 = "bar";
  return a as TypeB;
});
```

this is the best solution i could find, would appreciate more idiomatic solutions that 1) dont involve modifying TypeA, and 2) dont involve the use of `any`. Thank you.