# agGrid add new dynamically constructed row

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid

I am creating a generic grid component that would show data for schema that I don't know anything about at compile time. Data updates (and row additions) come as sparse arrays (row4,col7='abc'; row8,col2=456). 
I am generating ColDef set at runtime.

I believe I understand how to grab a row by key and set data on it using the columnApi. But how do I create a new row without knowing its type? A good analogy is creating a row from a dictionary of column name to value. I am also a bit new to TypeScript and JavaScript... Maybe I am missing something obvious because of this...

Thank you.

Comment: why -1? Just curious. Does not make mach difference to me... What is it, "hit and run", or beneath you to explain? Why do you come here then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching for more specific terms:

```
let anObj ={};
anObj['dynProp'] = 'my dynamic value';
expect(anObj.dynProp).toBe('my dynamic value');//this passes; using Karma
```

Taken from below, answered by Angelo R.; the accepted answer is about slightly different...
[How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)