# Typescript error: TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

this is part of my code:

```js
const myObj: object = {}
const propname = 'propname'

myObj[propname] = 'string'
```

but I got error:

```sh
ERROR in path/to/file.ts(4,1)
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"propname"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'propname' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

What is wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript

Answer (score 331, accepted):

You have to define what kind of index type the object has. In your case it is a `string` based index.

```
const myObj: {[index: string]:any} = {}
```

Comment: Thanks! `Record<string, any>` also works

Comment: When I CTRL+click on object  property ( i.e. myObj.someProperty ) Vs Code jumps to type definition instead of property as it was before type definition, is there a way to overcome that?

Answer (score 53):

Below are a few solutions to solve the "`TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type`" error when accessing properties via array-access.

**Original code**:

```js
const myObj: object = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'  // Error!
```

Note: **This does not work** because the index-signature is still undefined:

```js
const myObj: {propname: any} = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'  // Error!
```

---

**Solution 1**: Implicit define the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

```js
const myObj: {[key: string]: any} = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'
```

**Solution 2**: Use an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) to provide the index signature

```js
interface IStringIndex {
    [key: string]: any
}

const myObj: IStringIndex = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'
```

**Solution 3**: Use an interface and extend the [`<Record>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```js
interface IStringIndex extends Record<string, any> {}

const myObj: IStringIndex = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'
```

**Solution 4**: Define a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) with the index signature

```js
type MyObject = {
    [key: string]: any
    propname?: any
}

const myObj: MyObject = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'
```

**Solution 5**: Combination of an interface to describe the index-signature and a type alias to describe valid properties:

```js
interface IStringIndex extends Record<string, any> {}
type MyObject = IStringIndex & {
    propname?: string
}

const myObj: MyObject = {}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'
```

**Solution 6**: Define a list of valid (string) property names:

```js
type ValidProps = 'propname' | 'value'
interface IStringIndex extends Record<ValidProps, any> {}

const myObj: IStringIndex = {
    propname: 'my prop',
    value: 123
}
const prop = 'propname'
myObj[prop] = 'string'
```

*Note: All properties from the `ValidProps` list must be present when assigning the object!*

Comment: How do you create an object that allows any properties on it?

Comment: Solution 3 worked for me, also is syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 29):

In case you have an interface / class defined and it still throws that error, you could use `keyof` as follows:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  propertyA: string;
  propertyB: string;
}

const object: SomeInterface = {propertyA: 'A', propertyB: 'B'};

for ( const prop in object ) {
  const value = object[prop]; // <-- will throw an error
  const typedValue = object[prop as keyof SomeInterface]; // <-- will do fine
}
```

Otherwise you could "hack" it by adding generic property to that interface / class which would go through, but it opens quite a different door for type unsafety :)

```
interface SomeInterface {
  propertyA: string;
  propertyB: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Comment: this helped me:  `const typedValue = object[property as keyof SomeInterface]`

Comment: The above line of code unstuck me also. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

const myObj: object = {'foo': 'bar'}

const propname = 'foo';

```
(myObj as any)[propname] = 'baz';
```

Comment: this seems to work, but for my small mind it seems weird to me.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the: tsconfig.json, and set the below options

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
}

const listOfArray: Array<any> = [];
for(const Id in MyObject)
{
   listOfArray.push(dataList[Id]);//TS7053 Error here -- Fixed by doing above things
}
```

Facing the same error when I tried to Push the result which comes from `MyObject [{Id: value 1},{Id: 2},{Id: 3}]`.

Answer (score 3):

use `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` tsconfig.
detail doc about this config: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors

Comment: Note, that this will not work in 2024 anymore: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51909

Answer (score 2):

Create TS Map intead.

```
const myObj = new Map();
myObj.set('propname', "something");

const propname = 'propname'
myObj.get(propname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with JSON objects. The "type" key is used in the switch statement and case options are strings.

In older versions of Ionic was enough:

```
var jsonMessage: JSON;
```

In newer versions I had to use:

```
var jsonMessage: {"type": string, "data": string};
```

or

```
var jsonMessage: {"type": any, "data": any};
```