# ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(391,9): error TS7017: Element > implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Foo' has no index signature

Tags: typescript

I am not assigning new property like this:[Typescript error: TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833469/typescript-error-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type) Hence any would not work.  I am just trying to edit an existing proprety based on an interface

```
   updateFieldTest(index: number, field: string ) {
        const tasks: Foo[] = [
            {foo:1,bar:2},
            {foo:1,bar:2},
            {foo:1,bar:2},
            {foo:1,bar:2},
        ]
        const task = tasks[index];
        task[field] = 4
    }
```

The interface Foo

```
export  interface Foo {
    foo: number,
    bar: number
}
```

Gives this error

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(391,9): error TS7017: Element
>   implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Foo' has no index signature

As temporary solution, changed `field: string` to `field: 'foo' | 'bar'`

But is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript error: TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833469/typescript-error-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Comment: @MuratKaragöz This is not a duplicate. I am not assigning new property like this:Typescript error: TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type Hence any would not work. I am just trying to edit an existing proprety based on an interface  Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the index type for `Foo` which is `string` derived from `field:string`.

```
interface Foo {
    foo: number,
    bar: number,
    [index: string]: any
}
```