# array find method error element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I'm facing a problem with Typescript linting. The scenario is that data is coming from the API which contains an array of objects.

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "politics",
    "slug": "politics",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "sport",
    "slug": "sport",
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "weather",
    "slug": "weather",
  }
]
```

What I want is when there any new object is created and tries to post on the server before that we have to make sure `slug` is unique or not. So I created a utility function named `uniqueStr` that will check that slug is exist or not.

`ICategory.ts`:

```
export interface Category {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    parent: number;
}
```

`utility.ts`

```
import {Category} from './ICategory';

export const uniqueStr = (property: string, compareValue: string, data: Category[]): string => {

    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        const objectFind = data.find((element) => {
            return element[property] === compareValue;
        });
        // If not undefined
        if (objectFind) {
            const message = `${property} value should be unique.`;
            alert(message);
            throw new Error(message);
        } else {
            // Return value
            return compareValue;
        }
    }
    return compareValue;
};
```

At the following line `return element[property] === compareValue` Typescript linter is giving an error.

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Category'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Category'.
```

Comment: I think the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833469/typescript-error-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jérôme I already have seen this question but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indexable-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) to specify that properties an instance of the `Category` interface can be accessed via string index.

Example:

```js
interface Category {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    parent: number;
    [key: string]: number | string;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Could you tell me why I'm facing a problem with `data.unshift` when trying to add an object `TS2345: Argument of type 'Category' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` 

`const category: Category =  {
             id: 1,
             name: name,
             slug: uniqueStr('slug',slug, data),
             parent: 1
         };
         data.unshift(category);`

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
const index = this.selectedActors.findIndex((a: { name: any; }) => a.name === actor.name);
```

earlier is used this

```
const index = this.selectedActors.findIndex((a => a.name === actor.name);
```