# How do you loop through objects to set its values in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to set each value in an object using Typescript, but I can't seem to get it to work in any elegant way. This is what I have:

```
const myObject = {
    keyA: '',
    keyB: '',
};

for (const key in myObject) {
    myObject[key] = 'something';
}
```

But I get the typescript error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type `{ keyA: string; keyB: string; }`.
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type `{ keyA: string; keyB: string; }`.  TS7053

Shouldn't Typescript know that key must be a key of myObject?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833507/3233827

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 but then I lose the beauty of Typescript. My object has a specific set of keys, and if I set that type, I don't get type checking for my keys

Comment: @nickzoum It does remove the error, but then I don't get type checking for the keys in the object anymore. My object has a specific set of keys, and I want Typescript to enforce them

Comment: Add this to your code, run as javascript, to see potential issues: `Object.prototype.trolled = 123;`

Comment: @ASDFGerte has pointed out the issue: Typescript only knows what it can know (and has to assume the worst) *statically, at compile time*. Iteration happens at *runtime*.

Comment: @nickzoum that does seems to work, but then I have to type in all the fields twice, which is what I wanted to avoid

Comment: Btw, other related material is e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870

Comment: @JaredSmith It does seem to be able to in other cases, such as when doing if (keyA in myObject) then myObject.keyA

Comment: @Spliid that's because you can verify a literal statically, which you can't do with random string assignment.

Comment: Not helpful whoever closed this issue. How do you set type properly in the loop??