# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 0: { label: string; color: string; }; }'

Tags: node.js, angular

This is my App.component.html code.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-order>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ order.user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.totalPrice | currency}}</td>
     <td>{{ order.dateOfOrdered | date: 'short'}}</td>
     <td>
       <p-tag [value]="orderStatus[order.status].color"></p-tag>
     </td>
     <td>
       <p-button styleClass="p-button-primary mr-2" icon="pi pi-eye" 
           (onClick)="showOrder(order.id)"> 
       </p-button>
       <p-button styleClass="p-button-danger mr-2" icon="pi pi-trash" 
           (onClick)="deleteOrder()">
       </p-button>
     </td>
   </tr>
</ng-template>
```

This is my app.component.ts code.

```js
const ORDER_STATUS = {
  0 : {
    label : 'Pending',
    color: 'warning'
  },
}

export class OrdersListComponent implements OnInit {
  orderStatus = ORDER_STATUS;
}
```

In my case am getting this error:

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ 0: { label:
> string; color: string; }; }'.
>
> 22 <p-tag [value]="orderStatus[order.status].color">

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the value for `order`? Or sample data (`orders`) to reproduce?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833469/typescript-error-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type