# Angular Mat-Table Dynamic Property In Cell

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-mat-table) but my case is slightly different with dynamic data (both Element and Columns) from Api let's say

**Element_Data**

```
{name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'}
```

**displayedColumn**

```
["name","weight","symbol"]
```

In my case I loop into displayedColumn like this and push to column

```
for(var x = 0 ;x<this.displayedColumns.length;x++){

  this.columns.push( {columnDef: this.displayedColumns[x], header: this.displayedColumns[x],    cell: 
 (element: any) => `${ element.date}`});
}

 this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);

 this.DataSet  =  Observable.of(this.Element_Data);
```

**Problem**

This problem is with this statement

> ${ element.date}`}

as I am using dynamic data I cannot write static property name for each element it should be dynamic something like

```
 {this.displayedColumns[x]}
```

so that the correct value will return on calling

```
<mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
```

I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript) but no luck in this case of "column as property name"

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.date` is equivalent to `element['date']` so you can put any string object inside it. [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp)

Comment: good approach but it is not working in this scenario , the result is undefined in case of dynamic but fine in case of static string type inside array , but it gives me a hint voting up