# How to add method to an object with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this case where I want to test a function with some specific `this`. But typescript either won't let me add the method to the object, or if I define it as `any` then my interface is not being used.

example:

```
import getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange from './index'
import Db from '../Db'

test('getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange', async () => {
  const db = Db() as any
  db.getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange = getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange
  const torrents = await db.getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange({startDate: '2019-03-03', endDate: '2019-03-08', limit: 100})
})
```

and in the other file

```
import {Torrent} from '../interfaces'

interface GetMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange {
  (GetMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRangeSettings: {
    startDate: string,
    endDate: string,
    limit: number
  }): Promise<Torrent[]>
}

const getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange: GetMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange = async function ({startDate, endDate, limit}) {
  return []
}

export default getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do with the least amount of code repetition? I don't want to define `getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange` twice, and I don't really want to import/export it either.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that error arise from line

```
db.getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange = getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange
```

This issue and workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript). In short, ts knows, that `db` hasn't property `getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange` and reports error.

For your specific purpose I suggest not adding property `getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange` but use `call` method of all JS functions, which allows to provide arbitrary `this` and preserves type safety.

```
getMostPeersTorrentsFromDateRange.call(db, {startDate: '1', endDate: '2', limit: 3})
```

Here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQEIAoCUiDeBYAKEUQCcBTKEEpHRABxLjoC5EByARgCYBmNxAL6EhBQjDBQyJYAEMIZRAHEKAWTgBnKAAUyU9QBU4JchPUAxRgFtkMyQCUZYAOYL8RROmVQ1mnXsPGZKYWcNa2ZA7OZADKFLDO6qxuxMSaMiRQNpKsmiTiTgA0hCmIQQAmWWQ5UHnORe7EADYwljBQrGAglgBGUsWCmKxaVjDqZAA8jgCeANoAugB8woSEEAiaiC7eGtq6JAZGJlDmVpWRLqxePrv+h0HHIWH2ji6IALyIMupTkIigkLAEB4cGkMpUCqUwBVwhDmq0oAJsMlSBQqEh5stRFj-tB4EhJJoOFhcP0AG7pRBlbrvFAYTAAbn6W2ufn2ASOJ1CZxeZAAdBAZI1GugqRCQVB0plwqxOGwIeVKjKuHLEHC2qweIjhEA)

Comment: using call still seems to lose the interface, I can put limit as a string and get no type error. my goal is to enforce the interface of the function but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: No, `call` preserves types. Look at playfround link I've provided. Maybe you've not removed `DB() as any` typecast or use old version of typescript.

Comment: I'm using 3.7 and I have remove `as any`. and it's still not working. It is working in playground but not in my environment for some reason. I do have "strict": false not sure if that's the problem but I can't enable it.