# what is any after equal symbol in typescript object

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

I was going through [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444150/8701527)

Here the author have answered: // How I tend to intialize

```
var foo:IFoo = <any>{};
```

I tried to google but I wasn't able to find any info regarding it. What does it mean the part `<any>{};`?

Also is `{} as any` equal to `<any>{}`?

Comment: You are probably also better off _not_ casting to any. When you initialize the object and cast from any, presumably it's because IFoo actually has properties. You are going to catch more bugs avoiding this.

Answer (score 1):

> Also is `{} as any` equal to `<any>{}`?

Yes, `<any>` is the old syntax. See [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

> What does it mean?

See also  See [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.
>
> Type assertions have two forms.
>   One is the “angle-bracket” syntax
>   and the other is the as-syntax

This `any` trick is to get this compiling:

```
interface IFoo{

  someProp: string
}

var foo:IFoo = <any>{};
```

As this will complain as the someProp is missing:

```
var foo:IFoo = {}
```