# Creating dynamic objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

I'm using ReactJs with typescript and I need to create a dynamic object interface for example:

```
language: {name: string}
```

but I need the language key to be dynamic. for example:
I need to be able to add an object like below to the state

```
en_us: {name: english}
```

Comment: You should be able to do that using []

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets to define object keys as `[name: type]`:

```js
type language = {
  [langCode: string]: { // this allows you to use any string as key
    name: string
  }
}

const languages: language[] = [
  { en_us: { name: "english" } },
  { pt_br: { name: "brazilian-portuguese"} }
]
```