# How to dynamically add a new property while updating the draft on immer?

Tags: typescript, immer.js

Consider the following code, where line 2 fails with `Property 'newProperty' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<MyObject>'.  TS7053`

```
// data is of type MyObject which until now has only a property myNumber
const payload = produce(data, (draft) => {    
  draft['newProperty'] = 'test';              // Property 'newProperty' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<MyObject>'.  TS7053
});
```

How can I dynamically add a new property to the draft or change the type of the draft to a type which already includes the `newProperty`? I do not want to have `newProperty` in the `MyObject` type itself.

Comment: This is not a great solution, but couldn't you just cast it to `any`?

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. Yet I am wondering if there is any better / official way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript, I pretty sure you might want to take a look at this one. In case if you need to add any new property even in a for loop. This question is quite common in fact but all solutions seem like just defeats the original purpose of typescript. I don't think there is a truly elegant way to do it. Otherwise you just need to add a new property as a interface for the parameter.

Comment: You seem to want to operate like a simple dictionary. The question is ofcourse, what will you do with that object afterwards, and does it make sense (the code you are showing here doesn't offer any benefit to a consumer afterwards, they are not aware it now has new properties, so what is your end goal)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep this new type on `payload` you will have to cast new type on parameter `data`:

```js
let payload = produce(data as MyObject & { newProperty: string }, (draft) => {
  draft["newProperty"] = "test";
})
```

If you are not interested in keeping your type on `payload`, you can modify type of `draft` either in parameter of function, or inside: `(draft as MyObject & { newProperty: string })[newProperty] = "test"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add new properties to preexisting types by using the union operator: `&`. The code below should solve your problem.

```
(draft: WritableDraft<MyObject> & { newProperty : string }) => {
  // put the rest of your code here
}
```

## Edit

After looking at Linda Paiste's answer, I think there are a few issues with the approach I took above. My answer does add a property to the type, which removes any error you would get from accessing or modifying the `newProperty` attribute in the function. However, it is more verbose and difficult to maintain if types or variables names are changed in the future. Additionally, it forces the caller of the function to pass in an object that contains the `newProperty` property, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: I think `{newProperty: string}` should go into `<>`, so it would be `WritableDraft<MyObject & { newProperty : string }>`

Comment: @ezhikov You might be right, but I can't tell because the definition for `WritableDraft` isn't provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually fine to return a new object from `produce` as long as you don't *also* modify the `draft`.  The docs on [returning new data from producers](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/return) show an example with a `switch` where some cases modify the draft and others return a new state.  That is fine as long as you don't do do both in the same case.

```
const payload = produce(data, (draft) => {
    return { ...draft, newProperty: "test" };
});

const n = payload.myNumber; // number
const s = payload.newProperty; // string
```

Pros:

- No `as` assertions needed
- `payload` gets correct type `{ newProperty: string; myNumber: number; }`

Cons:

- Doesn't actually make use of Immer's capabilities

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WvpEAN)

Comment: No longer works as TS 3.7.5

Comment: Interesting!  It definitely used to work when I wrote this answer.  I suspect that the change is probably in the `immer` package types rather than in TS core, but I'll have to look into it.