# How to dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript by using Record correctly?

Tags: typescript

I try to define a type which can assign any key in an object. Then, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441178/10090927) is a good answer.

```
type AnyMap = Record<string, any>;
const obj: AnyMap = {};
const obj1: AnyMap = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}
```

However, I found `AnyMap` could also be assigned to an array and it doesn't show any errors.

```
const arr1: AnyMap = ['a', 'b'];
```

I just want `AnyMap` to only define the type of **object**, not including **array**. So, I try to create another type.

```
type UnknownMap = Record<string, unknown>;

// obj2 is works fine
const obj2: UnknownMap = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}

// obj3 is works fine
const obj3: UnknownMap = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b'
}

// arr2 throws an error
// Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UnknownMap'. Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'.(2322)
const arr2: UnknownMap = ['a', 'b'];
```

The result of `UnknownMap` seems good to me. It only define the type of **object** and throws an error of **array**. Finally, I have two question that I don't quite understand.

1. If I only want to define the type of **object** and doesn't want to include the type of **array**. Is it better to use `UnknownMap` instead of `AnyMap` ?
2. Why `const arr2: UnknownMap = ['a', 'b']` throws the error `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UnknownMap'. Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'.(2322)` ? I don't know why it throws an error just because I replace `any` with `unknown` in `Record`. Also, I don't know why `obj3` is works fine but `arr2` throws an error.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAsgQzFAvFAShAxgewCcATAHgGdhCBLOAcwBopkEA+AbgCgC5Kp8ARgCsAjAC5YCFGkwBvTlEXMJAcmQqGCpQNUCVnAL7d8vYM0KFxkpKgxQA2mo1QVegLpdOoSFACqcAGs4fAB3OGk7HAISCipaRigAV0DgsI5jU35hACYJfyDQ8Ns5LUVkVXVNJSgdFz1DDL5BIQBmPJTCiJLqgAYKjVKoK1d9IwB6MagAdQALEHNCbKhgGcJQ8mWZ6AgLIigAfkazZAtcvw6wrocnJhGPTk4JqAAVLahCCHJEgBszfAAzKA8cj4b4QAB033wdCg1A2yG+3ygEAAjokEct8C51ODHpNZvMhIk+CdFps1iENittrtCAdGqCIVC6AAKAAGzRa9h6bjsABJZJzuW4DGyAJQMsGQ6Hs0nZYX82Ry4WisVAA)

I hope the link above can help to explain my question well. If there is any description that makes you confused, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: But arrays _are_ objects?

Comment: (2) is indeed strange.

Comment: I'm not quite sure either, and I'm interested in the answer. I think it has to do with type inference. cos this works

`const arr2: UnknownMap = (['a', 'b'] as unknown) as UnknownMap;`

sorry can't seem to insert the link

Comment: FWIW this seems to be specific to `Array`, a self written type with the same behavior as `Array` behaves differently in this situation. [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArmAlgRzgUxgXhgZQJ4C2ARiADYAUAlANwBQUeADhjmqQGYCCATtwIZ4APABUAfFhgBvGKTRgA5lAAWALhhg4xNNwA0MANoBrNHjUat3ALprhe-fmJkAdIija+UEFapqAkm-4iWX93T24RUWoYbjQAN20INDUqLHFYkEQAExgAXzpaUEhYRDBMtAAPYSYkqWi0PkzwUjwDY1N1TSJtaxhobhL5XIlpXLpC6Bg+XgEq5jUefiE+gfFsfUsx8AmQAHcwBYE1XDYuaaWofoVVgw3aAq3i0orhKfk0KABGNWkjEzVlhQ9BCGMC7MBDbAlMqVaqbIowKHPV7vABM31af16FwGQLAILBEMmZ1maDhE0RlWRUAAzOjfu0AfJcfi9oSwQc8NQgA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1**

> Why const arr2: UnknownMap = ['a', 'b'] throws the error Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UnknownMap'. Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'.(2322) ? I don't know why it throws an error just because I replace any with unknown in Record. Also, I don't know why obj3 is works fine but arr2 throws an error.

In order to better understand this error, please switch to TypeScript 4.4.0 version in TS playground.

Since, there was error messages improvement.

I believe this error (from TS 4.3.*):
`Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UnknownMap'. Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'` 
Is not correct because `string[]` has index signature.

See `lib.es5.d.ts`. This is a part of Array type declaration:

```js
// lib.es5.d.ts
interface Array<T> {
    [n: number]: T
}
```

If you switch to TS `4.4.0 - beta` in TS playground, you will se this error:

```js
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UnknownMap'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'string[]'
```

Above error message makes sense.

In order to understand TS error message better, consider next example:

```js
declare var arr: { [prop: number]: string };
declare var rec: { [prop: string]: unknown };

arr = rec; // error
rec = arr // ok
```

Error message:

```
Type '{ [prop: string]: unknown; }' is not assignable to type '{ [prop: number]: string; }'.
  'string' and 'number' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

Hence, we can reduce our problem to this:

```js
declare var str: string;
declare var unk: unknown;

str = unk;
unk = str
```

So, the main problem here, that `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'`, whether `any` is assignable to type `string`.

Let's go back to our main error message:

```js
type AnyMap = Record<string, any>;
const obj1: AnyMap = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}
const arr1: AnyMap = ['a', 'b'];

type UnknownMap = Record<string, unknown>;

const obj2: UnknownMap = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}
const obj3: UnknownMap = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b'
}

const arr2: UnknownMap =  ['a', 'b']; // error
```

Message:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'UnknownMap'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'string[]'
```

Since `Record<string, unknown>` is just an alias for

```js
{
    [x: string]: unknown;
}
```

and `['a', 'b']` infered to `string[]`, or in other words to

```js
{
    [x: number]: string;
}
```

index signature for `[x: number]: string;` is not assignable to `[x: string]: unknown`, because `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Keep in mind, that `x:string` as an index signature itself is assignable to `x:number` and vie versa, because according to JS specification, all keys are evaluated to `string`.

**Part 2**

> If I only want to define the type of object and doesn't want to include the type of array. Is it better to use UnknownMap instead of AnyMap ?

In order to distinguish dictionary and array, you need to infer this type from somewhere. You can either create an utility type for such purpose of infer it from function arguments. Please keep in mind, there is no `negation` operator in TypeScript.

Consider this example:

```js
type Primitives =
    | string
    | number
    | symbol
    | boolean
    | undefined
    | bigint
    | null // not sure how you want to treat this one :D

type AnObject<T = any> =
    T extends Primitives | Array<any> ? never : T
{

    type Test = AnObject<Record<number, 2>> // ok
    type Test2 = AnObject<[]> // never
    type Test3 = AnObject<2> // never
}

const onlyObj = <T,>(obj: AnObject<T>) => { }
onlyObj([]) // Error
onlyObj(2) // Error
onlyObj({}) // ok
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/type-negation), in my blog, you can find more examples/information regarding type negation in typescript.

Comment: In the same [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAsgQzFAvFAShAxgewCcATAHgGdhCBLOAcwBopkEA+AbgCgC5Kp8ARgCsAjAC5YCFGkwBvTlEXMJAcmQqGCpQNUCVnAL7d8vYM0KFxkpKgxQA2mo1QVegLpdOoSFACqcAGs4fAB3OGk7HAISCipaRihKGnoOY1N+YQAmCX8g0PDbOS1FZFV1TSUoHRc9QzS+QSEAZhzA4LCIosqABjKNYqgrV30jAHpRqAB1AAsQc0JMqGBpwlDyJenoCAsiKAB+erNkC2y-NvzOhycmYY9OTnGoABVNqEIIcgBXABszfAAzKA8cj4b4QAB033wdCg1HWyG+3ygEAAjp8EUt8C51OCHhMZnMhJ8+McFhtViF1sstjtCPt6qCIVC6AAKAAGjSa9m6bjsABJZJzuW4DGyAJQMsGQ6Hs0mZYX82Ry4WisVAA) I added string instead of unknown the error still persist. Seems like bug to me.

Comment: What do you say @captain-yossarian?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik yes, it is strange for me either. I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks for your explanation. It's easy to understand.

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian, I found a weird part. For the case of `Array`, it should be `[x: number]: string` assign to the `[x: string]: unknown` right? However, your answer says `[x: string]: unknown; is not assignable to [x: number]: string`. It seems your answer make it reverse.

Comment: @bcjohn yes, I made a mistake. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @bcjohn we use `unknown` when we have to do narrowing on types. This is kind of mention on the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type). This is the legit use case of unknown.