# Dynamic TypeScript key name

Tags: json, typescript

I am using TypeScript and i am wondering how can i "type" the following object.

```json
{
    "code": 52,
    "somerandomstring123":"Some Data"
}
```

The thing is, that the KEY **NAME** `somerandomstring123` is dynamically generated string and is not constant.
So for example, the JSON could've been like this:

```json
{
    "code": 52,
    "someOTHERstring456":"Some Data"
}
```

I tried using `[key:string]: string` like this:

```js
interface SomeObjectData {
code: number;
[target: string]: string;
}
```

but it returns an error of: `Property 'code' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string'.`

P.S.: The dynamic named property (e.g. somerandomstring123) value type is a string, so using `string  | number` is not something i need.

Comment: if you know it will either be a string or a number you can simply use a union. `[target: string]: string | number`

Comment: @about14sheep uh oops i fixed my post, i am not talking about the value type but the key type.

Comment: I think @about14sheep is correct. That should make TS happy. The problem is that this "dynamic" expression: `[target: string]: string` will also encompass the `code` property, so it needs to be a union.

Comment: There is no specific object type in TypeScript corresponding to the set of values you wish to support. You can make a generic constraint like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9pk7w) which requires an object has a numeric `code` property and that other properties must be of `string` type, but using it has lots of caveats.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218); yours asks about "one" dynamic key, but the issue is nearly the same (indeed your attempt at using `[key: string]: string` shows that). Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Try `type SomeObjectData = Record<string, string> & { code: number, /* other non-string properties */ };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
type SomeObjectData = {
  [key: string]: string; // dynamic properties
} & {
  code: number; // static properties
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the union type for the target.

```
interface SomeObjectData {
    [target: string]: string | number;
    code: number;
}

const data:SomeObjectData = { code: 12}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to allow _all other properties_ to be `number` just to be able to add `code: number`? If the OP knows that the dynamic properties are strings, then `string | number` is excess; if the OP doesn't know the type of dynamic properties, the type should rather be `unknown`

Comment: @Dima Parzhitsky is right.
I know that the dynamically named property will always be a string.