# how to update dynamically a variable object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
      let ={
      "name": "jacob",
      "age": 22 }
```

I want to update it dynamically into
{
"name": "jacob",
"age": 22 ,
"dob":number
}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It is not clear.

Comment: i get data like this let data1 ={
      "name": "jacob",
      "age": 22 } after some other purpose i need more data from user so i want to update data1  like dob key value

Comment: So why can't you just set `obj.dob = 'something'`?

Comment: it gives error dob property did not exist

Comment: Is that a TypeScript warning or an actual JavaScript error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript

Comment: Nafis Islam thank you save my work

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is if you are using TS, then you need to define the type for the object with the dob key as optional. Otherwise, TS will keep giving the error and your Angular application will not compile.

The current way you are trying to do has no type defined for the object and TS automatically evaluated the type to {name: string, age: number} and throws an error when you try to add another property.

Note:- It would be great if you go through the basics of Typescript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript    I was asking something like that and found what I was looking for