# TypeScript: dynamically declaring properties based on a static array of strings

Tags: typescript, types

I'm writing some frontend code in TypeScript, creating some [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) by hand.

Custom Elements let me define "observed attributes" as an array of strings. I want all of these observed attributes to also be properties on the class, so that I can for example `myElement.attr1 = 'value'` instead of `myElement.setAttribute('attr1', 'value')`. Right now, I'm achieving that with this metaprogrammy code:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'];
  }
}

for (const attr of MyElement.observedAttributes) {
  Object.defineProperty(MyElement.prototype, attr, {
    get: function() { return this.getAttribute(attr) },
    set: function(value) {
      if (value === null) this.removeAttribute(attr);
      else this.setAttribute(attr, value);
    }
  });
}
```

This works great, but TypeScript does not know about the properties I'm adding, even though they're all completely static. Is there some trick I can use to tell typescript that I'm adding properties for each string in `observedAttributes`?

I've tried something like this:

```js
const myObservedAttributes = {
  'attr1': true,
  'attr2': true,
  'attr3': true,
};

type DynamicAttrs = {
  [Key in keyof typeof myObservedAttributes]: string | null;
}

class MyElement extends HTMLElement implements DynamicAttrs {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return Object.keys(myObservedAttributes);
  }
}

// ... Object.defineProperty loop from above
```

but of course TypeScript complains that I'm not implementing any of the properties in `DynamicAttrs` because it doesn't understand `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Does the following help:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript?rq=1)

Comment: I think that solution is equivalent to my `DynamicAttrs` type (which didn't work). It requires me to manually define each property, *and* keep a list of each property in the type. I want to only have one list of properties in my source code.

Comment: Hmm -- found this as well: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-assertion-signatures/

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrDVDW) using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Hey yeah that does seem to work: https://cutt.ly/K2FGdGp - thanks for the reference!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, it might be tomorrow evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's modify your `observedAttributes()` getter so that the return type will be a strongly typed array of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and not just `string[]`:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'] as const;
    }
}
```

The [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) tells the compiler to infer a more specific type for the value.  Now if you inspect `observedAttributes` with IntelliSense, you'll see that the type is

```
// (getter) MyElement.observedAttributes: readonly ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]
```

---

Now, if you want to tell TypeScript that you have augmented a class instance type, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to "re-open" the `interface` corresponding to the class instance.  For your example it could look like this:

```
interface MyElement extends Record<
    typeof MyElement.observedAttributes[number], string | null
> { }
```

As mentioned above, `typeof MyElement.observedAttributes` is `readonly ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]`. When we [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type with `number` (`typeof MyElement.observedAttributes[number]`) we get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the types of the elements: `"attr1" | "attr2" | "attr3"`.  By merging `Record<typeof MyElement.observedAttributes[number], string | null`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) into the `MyElement` interface, we're saying that a `MyElement` instance should have `attr1`, `attr2`, and `attr3` properties of type `string | null`.

---

Let's test it out, using [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) and merging the element type into the associated TypeScript interface so that the compiler knows about it:

```
if (!customElements.get("my-element"))
    customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);

interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    "my-element": MyElement;
}

const myEl = document.createElement("my-element");
// const myEl: MyElement

myEl.attr1 = "abc";
console.log(myEl.attr1.toUpperCase()) // "ABC"
myEl.attr2 = "def";
console.log(myEl.attr2.toUpperCase()) // "DEF"
myEl.attr2 = null;
console.log(myEl.attr2) // null
myEl.attr3 = "ghi";
console.log(myEl.attr3.toUpperCase()) // "GHI"
```

Looks good.  The compiler understands that `myEl` is a `MyElement` and therefore that it has `attr1`, `attr2`, and `attr3` properties, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBREBTAtigdgF2igHtlgCYwASAKrADLLpa4DeAUNG9BNmNgJbDQBzFLgD2AIwgoATgDcUxAILZsUnmICuRCAAoAlNBbsj0KcPVTM0ANoBybioCMNgDTQ7yqQCYXb+1IDMNgC60JDQwCKYnADcrOwAvnFsAPTJ0NpCytL6CHQYOAB04pKy8koqapooEABcJihgxJEg8NYARH4Oba4dHp7d0L0q-m1BzInMqdAAIiigYFLcPJHQGFICPJgCzJtEUgBmYMAocEio+bgERJik0ABKcyJSxAA8SdDY8AAOKCL7p3kGEUJNI5IoPJUtFZMOo0GJpEFXJxVFtoAAfaAwkAgZgAPgM0Am+ye6QiUVwfmgfwB5yBxVBZQhGi0+kM7AA8mIAFZzbAFYgofabFAABSkIh+Uk+2lytMKX3F2BEnx+rj8rjZxkEwjq+3UmGAvBWegJpmw5ks2AAFjwIAVMuVVMyUNo-Pp4s53kZJNhdfrDctLNoZGAQOoUKyvVroDx-sHQ+HoABeFOY9TY-TW20FUxoERyR2Ql1u2LR4woECSD42u0+wvO10eVwhsMR0vRxJGeK6WITXbSQ7HaCUGiAnAUMACAByYAwsDAXwM7zaaHgAFoK-QcG06rKt9hezs4wBCYDqTgiNBj7B2zLaFfrzcXNq6XTvM8Xq9ym-8wXC++rhu34DHuFw9swzBkpwqxnMm0BNGeFwFMApjcCg14AY+wHgVMUG4KuyC7mc+4QQRIAFJ0cEdGIwBtLEUEiKgBQgCIAjaGRFEeA4BRKgAql8koAMKQC6r7QFMbQKAAQoJbTMBxfieFRAr7HRkGRBAjEoMxrHsWcnEqJ4PEiPxQkiXo+gSdMiAAGJyQpfRwViID0RpWk6WxDmGZZaTOfJ+l+P4VECDaakMUxLGeQFHj+MZpnSMJkgWeJaRtAA4mQACSbRAA)

Answer (score 1):

For such a situation, I'll use a factory :

```
    function getObservedElementFactory<ObservedProps extends string> (...observed: ObservedProps[]) {
        type IMyElement = {
            [P in ObservedProps] : ReturnType<HTMLElement["getAttribute"]>;
        };
    
        class MyElement extends HTMLElement { }
    
        for (const attr of observed) {
            Object.defineProperty(MyElement.prototype, attr, {
                get: function () { return this.getAttribute(attr); },
                set: function (value) {
                    if (value === null) this.removeAttribute(attr);
                    else this.setAttribute(attr, value);
                },
            });
        }
    
        return () => new MyElement() as MyElement & IMyElement;
    }
    
    export const createObservedOne = getObservedElementFactory("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
    
    const a = createObservedOne();
    a.attr1 = "toto"; // ok
    
    export const createObservedSecond = getObservedElementFactory("attr4", "attr5", "attr6");
    
    const b = createObservedSecond();
    b.attr4 = "toto"; // ok
```

There are some drawbacks, each generated factory has a different subclass of HTMLElement and other stuff. But this might help depending on your needs.