# How to add a field for an object after initialized and that field may or may not be added later?

Tags: typescript

```
let x = { a: 1, b: "2" } 
x.c = 3 // this throws an error (c is not assignable to {a: number, b: "string" })
```

is there a simple way to resolve this error without using the `any` type or defining types?

Comment: What do you mean by "defining types"?  Is `let x: {a: number, b: string, c?: number} = {a: 1, b: "2"}` "defining" a type? I'm mentioning one but not declaring it.  And if you can't mention a type then I'm not sure what you're looking for; could you [edit] to elaborate on your criteria?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I dynamically assign properties to an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript)

Comment: @berse2212 jcalz's comment is far from "the only correct answer". For example, it suggests without any good reason that `c` is optional. Judging by the code, it might not be.

Comment: I need more info from the OP before I can even begin to know what *a* correct answer is, let alone *the* correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving TypeScript the information about the type of `x`, so it has to infer the type from what it's got. What it's got is `{ a: 1, b: "2" }`, so it infers `x` to be `{ a: number, b: string }`. There's no property `c` here, thus you get an error when you try to assign something to `x.c`.

To fix this, you have to provide the type explicitly, rather than forcing TypeScript to infer it. This is what you can do:

```
interface Thing {
  a: number
  b: string
  c: number
}

const x = { a: 1, b: "2" } as Thing
x.c = 3
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WPKaZm).*

Note that `const x: Thing = { … }` won't work. That's because this syntax means "`x` can only be assigned a value that has properties `a`, `b`, and `c`". So, if you try to assign to it an object without property `c`, it would be a constraint violation and an error.

The syntax `const x = { … } as Thing` means "the object might look like it has some properties and values, but I know for certain that it is actually `Thing`".