# Typescript error property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript

In this line

`if(editItem.meta.hasOwnProperty('duration') && editItem.meta.duration){ ..`

typescript shows error :
 `Property 'duration' does not exist on type '{}'`

Now the problem is this property sometimes exists and sometimes does not. But typescript detects this as an error.

Comment: none of the solutions shared on this link have worked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710905/how-do-i-dynamically-assign-properties-to-an-object-in-typescript , this is a nested object and the error appears in the nested object only.

Comment: Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  TS doesn't treat `hasOwnProperty` as a type guard; you could write `"duration" in` instead, maybe, but this really all depends on concrete example code, which we don't have.

Comment: Try this trick and check if it works,

`(editItem.meta as any).duration`

Comment: @UtkarshDubey already tried.